# Cannot access a disposed context instance

Tags: c#, microservices, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-identity

My Application: .Net Core 3.1 Web application using Microservice architecture; Identity for Authorization & Authentication as separate Microservice API.

I have extended the standard AspNetUsers and AspNetRoles table with custom fields.
Getting the following error when I am trying to create a new Role using Identity RoleManager.

> Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this
> error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from
> dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context
> instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are
> calling 'Dispose' on the context instance, or wrapping it in a using
> statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the
> dependency injection container take care of disposing context
> instances. Object name: 'MembershipDBContext'.

Find my Code below

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            var idenConnectionString = Configuration["DbContextSettings:IdentityConnectionString"];
            var userConnectionString = Configuration["DbContextSettings:UserConnectionString"];
            var dbPassword = Configuration["DbContextSettings:DbPassword"];
            var builder = new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder(idenConnectionString)
            {
                Password = dbPassword
            };
            var userBuilder = new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder(userConnectionString)
            {
                Password = dbPassword
            };

            services.AddDbContext<MembershipDBContext>(opts => opts.UseNpgsql(builder.ConnectionString));
            services.AddDbContext<UserDBContext>(opts => opts.UseNpgsql(userBuilder.ConnectionString));

            

            services.AddIdentity<MembershipUser, MembershipRole>(options =>
            {
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
                options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+ ";
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
            }).AddRoles<MembershipRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<MembershipDBContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


            services.AddTransient<IIdentityMSService, IdentityMSService>();//IdentityMS
            services.AddTransient<IAdministrationService, AdministrationService>();//IdentityMS

            services.AddTransient<IIdentityMSRepository, IdentityMSRepository>();//IdentityMS
            services.AddTransient<IAdministrationRepository, AdministrationRepository>();//IdentityMS
            services.AddTransient<UserDBContext>();
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
            
            services.AddMediatR(typeof(Startup));
            RegisterServices(services);
        }
```

**MembershipDBContext.cs**

```
    public class MembershipDBContext : IdentityDbContext<MembershipUser,MembershipRole,string>
    {
        public MembershipDBContext(DbContextOptions<MembershipDBContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
    }
```

**AdministrationController**

```
 public class AdministrationController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IAdministrationMVCService _adminService;

        public AdministrationController(IAdministrationMVCService adminService)
        {
            _adminService = adminService;            
        }

        // GET: AdministrationController/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: AdministrationController/Create
        [HttpPost]
        //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAsync(MembershipRole rm)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    rm.CompanyId = 1;
                    await _adminService.AddRoles(rm);
                    //return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                    return View();
                }
                catch
                {
                    return View();
                }
            }
            return View();
        }

      
    }
```

**AdministrationApiController**

```
[HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody] MembershipRole role)
        {
            _adminMSService.AddRoles(role);
        }
```

**AdministrationRepository**

```
public class AdministrationRepository : IAdministrationRepository
    {
        private readonly RoleManager<MembershipRole> _roleManager;
        private readonly UserManager<MembershipUser> _userManager;

        public AdministrationRepository(RoleManager<MembershipRole> roleManager, UserManager<MembershipUser> userManager)
        {            
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        public async Task AddRolesAsync(MembershipRole rvm)
        {
            try
            {
                IdentityResult result = await _roleManager.CreateAsync(rvm);
                if (result.Succeeded) {

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

    }
```

I tried making the services and repositories as **singleton** but it didn't work either. What am I missing here? Any insights?

Comment: On which line of code do you get the error? I can't see where that issue would occur in this code.

Comment: getting exception on this particular line: IdentityResult result = await _roleManager.CreateAsync(rvm);

Comment: It's quite confusing because you have repositories, services all over, and you're not showing them all. The first thing to check - are you `await`ing **all** of the async methods? Because I see in the `AdministrationApiController` action, that you're not doing it there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solved the issue! As DavidG pointed out in his comment, I missed the 'await' keyword at certain places like AdministrationApiController.
Posting as an 'Answer' here, as I am unable to mark the comment as 'Answer'.